# exoplayer exo_play and exo_pause do not support "?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I'm trying to add as background "?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless".

But it does not seem to work, what could be the reason?

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@id/exo_play"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:contentDescription="@string/play"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play_36dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Comment: While this code my answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation will help current and future readers understand your answer even better.

Comment: @Paul by nothing happens you mean the ripple effect doesn't appear? Have you tried adding `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"`?